DOM Manipulation cloning nodes and placing values
I am trying to dynamically create a list, by cloning a li item, and then dynamically fill in the values of that list. Strangely, I get only the second item out of my object in that list. I have tried to review the code I wrote, but I cannot seem to find the issue?
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qaktdgb2/
<ul>
    <li>{name},{price}</li>
</ul>
    
<script>
function loop(node) {

  value = [{
      name: 'Bananas',
      price: '4'
    },
    {
      name: 'Candy',
      price: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Oranges',
      price: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Vegetables',
      price: '5'
    }
  ]

  let obj = Object.entries(value);
  let len = Object.entries(value).length;

  for (let k = 0; k < value.length; k++) {

    let object = Object.entries(obj[k][1]);

    for (const property in object) {

      let search = `${object[property]}`;
      let values = Object.entries(search.split(','));


      let textName = values[0][1];
      console.log(textName + ':' + values[1][1]);

      let regex = new RegExp("{\\s*" + textName + "[0-9]*\\s*}", "i");

      if (node.childNodes[k].innerHTML) {
        node.appendChild(node.childNodes[k].cloneNode(true));
        node.childNodes[k].innerHTML = node.childNodes[k].innerHTML.replace(regex, values[1][1]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function nodeParentList() {
  let parentList = [];
  var docElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
  for (var i = 0; i < docElements.length; i++) {
    parentList.push(docElements[i]);
  }
  return parentList;
}


var docElements = nodeParentList();
for (var i = 0; i < docElements.length; i++) {
  loop(docElements[i]);
}

</script>

Expected:
Bananas
Candy
Oranges
Vegetables

You were doing some weird things, that I even gave up to understand. So I've changed almost everything. So:

you can use querySelector rather than getElementsByTagName like in jQuery, just for ease of understanding.
nodeParentList function is useless, because you are creating an array, that has all elements of the second array. You already have an array, this step is not neccesary.
Why use RegExp here? It's slow and bad. Better to split it yourself by hand.
Why use Object.entries? You can just .forEach through the array.
You are non-stop using node.childNodes[k]. You can first assign it to a variable.

soooo.... I've rewrote the code for you lol, to match all these requirements + contain the fix
HTML
<ul>
  <li>{name},{price}</li>
</ul>

JavaScript
function loop(node) {
  let values = [{
      name: 'Bananas',
      price: '4'
    },
    {
      name: 'Candy',
      price: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Oranges',
      price: '2'
    },
    {
      name: 'Vegetables',
      price: '5'
    }
  ];

  let child = node.children[0];
  let syntax = child.innerHTML;
  values.forEach(obj => {
    if (child.innerHTML) {
      child.innerHTML = syntax.replace("{name}", obj.name).replace("{price}", obj.price);
      node.append(child);
      child = child.cloneNode(true);
    }
  });
}

loop(document.querySelector("ul"));


Your answer is very elegant, thank you! I accepted your answer as the correct one. Yes, I was working with the DOM and learning about it at the same time.
